# Constructive proof of existence of maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, constructive-mathematics

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring. We know that the existence of a maximal ideal of any such $R$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

> My question is, for what kind of $R$ is there a constructive proof that$R$ has a maximal ideal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7025/when-can-we-prove-constructively-that-a-ring-with-unity-has-a-maximal-ideal#

Comment: See also this paper [Making the use of maximal ideals constructive](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397507007608)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is very hard, even for rings that we can list the elements effectively. For example, in $\mathbb Q[X]$, such a proof as you require will give a algorithm capable of calculating the factorization of every rational polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to give a different answer using results from Reverse Mathematics. In Reverse Mathematics there is a classification of theorems expressed in a countable language in proof systems of different strengths. The main ones are: $RCA_{0} < WKL_{0} < ACA_{0}$.

In $RCA_{0}$ it is possible to provide (essentially constructive) *definitions* (for example of Countable Commutative Rings and Ideals), and of elementary lemmas, but $RCA_{0}$ is usually not powerful enough to *prove* corresponding major theorems.

The following theorem, is provable in Reverse Mathematics (description from "Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic", S.Simpson, 2010).

**Theorem III.5.4. $ACA_{0}$ proves that every countable commutative ring has a maximal ideal.**

This means, in effect, that "constructing" such a maximal ideal - in the general countable commutative ring case - would require solving the Halting problem.